Can I integrate Vue-Email in Nest.js to use with Novu Workflows?
I need to create Novu workflows and integrate Vue Email templates within these workflows. My backend is built with Nest.js, and Novu is already integrated. I'm unsure how a Frontend library can be incorporated into the Backend Novu Service file.
I would appreciate any example!
